# Qt5.5 application crashed in Ubuntu 14.04 when resolution change

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, ubuntu-14.04

I developed a simply application based on *Qt5.5* in *Ubuntu 14.04*. It runs normally. When I changed the resolution in Ubuntu, it crashed in most the time. The *Qt Creator* also crashes.

I try to I use the example of calendar. It also crashed.

How can I solve this problem?

Where I can look for a log in which I can try to find what is the reason for the crash?

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Thanks for replay, I can't see debugger, because the Qt Creator is also crashed, do you know there any way can see the log?